# CMake cannot find static wxWidgets under msys2

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw-w64, msys2

I'm trying to build a project with statically linked wxWidgets (I would just like to point out that it compiles&links just fine with shared libraries). This is relevant part of my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(wxWidgets_USE_STATIC ON)
find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED)
```

and this is error I get:

```
$ make
-- Boost version: 1.64.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   filesystem
--   program_options
CMake Error at C:/Dev/msys64/mingw64/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing: wxWidgets_LIBRARIES)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Dev/msys64/mingw64/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:377 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Dev/msys64/mingw64/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake:953 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:16 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

The static libraries are however installed

```
$ ls -l /mingw64/lib | grep libwx
-rw-r--r-- 1 tv185035 Domain Users 668K Sep 13 20:16 libwx_baseu_net-3.0.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 tv185035 Domain Users 453K Sep 13 20:14 libwx_baseu_net-3.0.dll.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 tv185035 Domain Users  84K Sep 13 20:16 libwx_baseu_xml-3.0.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 tv185035 Domain Users  68K Sep 13 20:14 libwx_baseu_xml-3.0.dll.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 tv185035 Domain Users 5.9M Sep 13 20:16 libwx_baseu-3.0.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 tv185035 Domain Users 4.6M Sep 13 20:14 libwx_baseu-3.0.dll.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 tv185035 Domain Users 6.8M Sep 13 20:16 libwx_mswu_adv-3.0.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 tv185035 Domain Users 3.2M Sep 13 20:14 libwx_mswu_adv-3.0.dll.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 tv185035 Domain Users 1.8M Sep 13 20:16 libwx_mswu_aui-3.0.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 tv185035 Domain Users 1.1M Sep 13 20:14 libwx_mswu_aui-3.0.dll.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 tv185035 Domain Users  28M Sep 13 20:16 libwx_mswu_core-3.0.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 tv185035 Domain Users  12M Sep 13 20:14 libwx_mswu_core-3.0.dll.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 tv185035 Domain Users 278K Sep 13 20:16 libwx_mswu_gl-3.0.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 tv185035 Domain Users 175K Sep 13 20:14 libwx_mswu_gl-3.0.dll.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 tv185035 Domain Users 2.6M Sep 13 20:16 libwx_mswu_html-3.0.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 tv185035 Domain Users 1.4M Sep 13 20:14 libwx_mswu_html-3.0.dll.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 tv185035 Domain Users 2.2M Sep 13 20:16 libwx_mswu_propgrid-3.0.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 tv185035 Domain Users 1.6M Sep 13 20:14 libwx_mswu_propgrid-3.0.dll.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 tv185035 Domain Users 331K Sep 13 20:16 libwx_mswu_qa-3.0.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 tv185035 Domain Users 193K Sep 13 20:14 libwx_mswu_qa-3.0.dll.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 tv185035 Domain Users 1.6M Sep 13 20:16 libwx_mswu_ribbon-3.0.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 tv185035 Domain Users 646K Sep 13 20:14 libwx_mswu_ribbon-3.0.dll.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 tv185035 Domain Users 3.6M Sep 13 20:16 libwx_mswu_richtext-3.0.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 tv185035 Domain Users 2.4M Sep 13 20:14 libwx_mswu_richtext-3.0.dll.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 tv185035 Domain Users 849K Sep 13 20:16 libwx_mswu_stc-3.0.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 tv185035 Domain Users 2.1M Sep 13 20:14 libwx_mswu_stc-3.0.dll.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 tv185035 Domain Users 404K Sep 13 20:16 libwx_mswu_webview-3.0.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 tv185035 Domain Users 634K Sep 13 20:14 libwx_mswu_webview-3.0.dll.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 tv185035 Domain Users 4.4M Sep 13 20:16 libwx_mswu_xrc-3.0.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 tv185035 Domain Users 1.1M Sep 13 20:14 libwx_mswu_xrc-3.0.dll.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 tv185035 Domain Users  90K Sep 13 20:16 libwxregexu-3.0.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 tv185035 Domain Users 2.7M Sep 13 20:16 libwxscintilla-3.0.a
```

I have no idea why it refuses to work. Will anyone please help?

Comment: Why are you running `make`? You should first generate the build files using `cmake` (although you should be using `ninja` anyways these days instead of `make`). You should point the CMake library search path towards the directory you listed, so it can search it for libraries.

Comment: `make` reruns `cmake` if needed no? But I tried to run `cmake` directly and result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, so I didn't get it to work with `wxWidgets_USE_STATIC`, but following does work (and produce static executable in release version)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

set(PROJECT_NAME "jibril")

project(${PROJECT_NAME})

set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)
set(BUILD_STATIC_LIBS ON)

string(TOLOWER "${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}" build_type_lower)

if(NOT build_type_lower MATCHES debug)
    set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
    set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME ON)
endif()
find_package(
    Boost REQUIRED
        system
        filesystem
        program_options
)
find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED)
string(
    REPLACE
        ";-Wl,--subsystem,windows;-mwindows"
        ""
        wxWidgets_LIBRARIES
        "${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES}"
)

add_executable(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
        src/main.cpp
)
target_include_directories(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
        PUBLIC ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        PUBLIC ${wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
target_compile_options(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
        PRIVATE -Wall
        PRIVATE -Wextra
        PRIVATE -Werror
        PRIVATE -Wduplicated-cond
        PRIVATE -Wduplicated-branches
        PRIVATE -Wlogical-op
        PRIVATE -Wrestrict
        PRIVATE -Wnull-dereference
        #PRIVATE -Wold-style-cast
        #PRIVATE -Wuseless-cast
        #PRIVATE -Wdouble-promotion
        PRIVATE -Wshadow
        #PRIVATE -Wformat=2
)
target_link_libraries(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
        ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
        ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES}

        optimized -static
        optimized -luuid
        optimized -lcomctl32
        optimized -loleacc
        optimized -lpng
        optimized -lz
        optimized -s
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made it works,

```
set(wxWidgets_USE_LIBS ON) <-- add this before find_package
find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED)
```

And specify the wxWidgets_LIB_DIR in cmake explicitly, example,

```
wxWidgets_LIB_DIR=W:/wxWidgets-3.0.4/lib/vc_x64_lib
```